# What is deferent in using between "context" and "localStorage" in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, react-context

I had this question during using context in ReactJS.
"context" is used to save global values which are used in children components.
Also `localStorage` is used to save global values.
So we can use both in same purpose.
What can we do better using context than using `localStorage` in ReactJS?

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs before writing a question :)

"Context lets us pass a value deep into the component tree without explicitly threading it through every component". It's React specific and the components rerenders when the values change.
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

LocalStorage is Web API and saves data in the browser. Changing localStorage won't trigger a rerender.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

It depends on what you need, read the docs and you will understand better.